# call a function specific from another script?

Tags: bash, shell

I wanna call a function specific from another script.

Example: I have 2 script files.

> - a.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash 
function test1(){
    echo "Output function test1!"
}

function test2(){
    echo "Output function test2!"
}
```

> - b.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
```

I want to call a function test1 (not test2) and output results in b.sh script.

My desired results:

```
#/usr/bin/b.sh
Output function test1!
```

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source the script that defines the functions, then call the function you want.

```
#!/bin/bash
source /usr/bin/a.sh
test1
```